# Latin phrases in 1787 letter from Danish bishop

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, christianity, epistula

This is a pretty complex mishmash of Danish, Latin, and Greek. With help from friends I have it almost fully translated, but two latin phrases have eluded me and block a full translation.

The context is the bishop writing to the provost about a problematic priest in the provost's juridiction (dated Nov 6, 1787). He finishes the letter like so (images at the end, partial translations below):

> snart er jeg færdig at sige som Paulus: ίδε, πηλίκοις γραμμασιν εγραψα
> τῇ εμῇ χειρί! men han skrev om vigtige Ting, og jeg som oftest, i
> Ligning derimod, *de lana caprina*. Begge vi, kjære gode Hr. Provst,
> maae lade os befalde διακονεῖν τραπέζαις, τόν λόγον του Θεου
> καταλείψαντας, istud vero profecto ȣη ἀρεστόν εςιν — *sic autem infatis
> erat*. Dog! jeg havde nær blevet mismodig, — ogsaa dette hører til
> εργον της διακονίας ἥμων, — og dermed trøstede, ville vi alle atter
> være glade og færdige til alt. Gud velsigne og bevare D.V.V., min
> aarvaagne og brave συνεργὸν [etc.]

With the Danish parts translated to English:

> I am almost ready to say like Paulus: ίδε, πηλίκοις γραμμασιν εγραψα
> τῇ εμῇ χειρί! but he wrote about important things, where as I, in
> comparison, *de lana caprina*. Both of us, dear Mr. Provost,
> must let us command διακονεῖν τραπέζαις, τόν λόγον του Θεου
> καταλείψαντας, istud vero profecto ȣη ἀρεστόν εςιν — *sic autem infatis
> erat*. And yet! I almost became dispirited, — this too belongs to
> εργον της διακονίας ἥμων, — and thus comforted, should we all be
> happy and ready for everything. God bless and keep [honorific style], my
> vigilant and brave συνεργὸν [etc.]

- The first greek passage is [Galatians 6:11](https://biblehub.com/text/galatians/6-11.htm) (See with what large letters I am writing to you with my own hand) with the first word changed from 2nd person plural to singular, ie addressing the provost. I read this as the bishop's frustration.
- de lana caprina = the goat's wool, ie. a trifle.
- Now comes parts of [Acts 6:2](https://biblehub.com/text/acts/6-2.htm) with its subphrases in practically reverse order (word # from link in parantheses), and interjected latin:

  - (Both of us, dear Mr. Provost, must let us command)
  - διακονεῖν τραπέζαις (#19-20) =  to attend tables
  - τόν λόγον του Θεου (#15-18) = the word of God
  - καταλείψαντας (#14) = having neglected
  - **istud vero profecto = ???**
  - ȣη ἀρεστόν εςιν (#10-12) = not desirable it is
  - **sic autem infatis erat = ???**
- εργον της διακονίας ἥμων = the work of our ministry
- συνεργὸν = colleague

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

istud vero profecto = but this in fact

sic autem in fatis est = but/now as fate would have it // but/now it was fated that // but such was my fate